# Reputation widget having issues again?

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-graph

There seem to be perennial problems with the reputation widget which appears in the upper left of the Stack Overflow page.  Yesterday, I earned +75 points on the question [Questionmark in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668183/questionmark-in-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment94194324_53668183), yet even more than 24 hours later, this answer does not appear in my achievements list from yesterday:

[image]

What prompted me to post here was that I thought SO might actually be ignoring the rep from my answer.  The score for the day is wrong, and it should be +255.  In fact, both the answers list and rep graph from my profile page do show this answer, and the correct daily rep score is being reported there:

[image]
[image]

Is there some sort of reporting bug in the achievements drop down which is occasionally causing certain achievements to be ignored?

Side not: I actually *did* see the upvotes from the answer discussed come into my inbox.  But, the answer never appeared, nor did those upvotes "stick" (that is, I saw +10, but nothing beyond this).